# How to turn a column of data into an 8x12 grid?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put values from 1 column into an 8x12 grid.

With the first value starting in the top left of the grid, moving to the right 12 cells, then offsetting 1 row from starting cell and having the data continue filling cells in this format.

I'm trying to replace

```vb
roneWS.Range("E6:N6") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B4:B13"))
roneWS.Range("C7:N7") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B14:B25"))
roneWS.Range("C8:N8") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B26:B37"))
roneWS.Range("C9:N9") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B38:B49"))
roneWS.Range("C10:N10") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B50:B61"))
roneWS.Range("C11:N11") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B62:B73"))
roneWS.Range("C12:N12") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B74:B85"))
roneWS.Range("C13:N13") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B86:B97"))
```

with an array/loop.

I came up with:

```vb
Dim ptWS As Worksheet, roneWS As Worksheet, rtwoWS As Worksheet, rthreeWS As Worksheet, rfourWS As Worksheet
Dim ptRng As Range, destRng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim ptArr() As Variant

Set ptWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PT")
Set roneWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS1")
Set rtwoWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS2")
Set rthreeWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS3")
Set rfourWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS4")


i = 4
Set ptRng = ptWS.Range("B4:B97")            'data that needs to be moved to other worksheets B4:B97 = 1st WS, C4:C97 = 2nd WS, D4:D97 = 3rd WS, E4:E97 = 4th WS
Set destRng = roneWS.Range("E6")            'destination range for WS1-WS4 starts at E6
ptArr = ptRng.Value                         'setting all values for the WS1 to ptArr

For i = LBound(ptArr) To UBound(ptArr)      

    If ptArr(i, 1) = ptWS.Cells(14, 2) Then             'move my way across the columns until I hit Col O then, offset back to Col C and repeat until the end (N13) is reached
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(1, -12)
        destRng = ptArr(i, 1)
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(0, 1)
    ElseIf ptArr(i, 1) = ptWS.Cells(26, 2) Then
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(1, -12)
        destRng = ptArr(i, 1)
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(0, 1)
    ElseIf ptArr(i, 1) = ptWS.Cells(38, 2) Then
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(1, -12)
        destRng = ptArr(i, 1)
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(0, 1)
    ElseIf ptArr(i, 1) = ptWS.Cells(50, 2) Then
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(1, -12)
        destRng = ptArr(i, 1)
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(0, 1)
    ElseIf ptArr(i, 1) = ptWS.Cells(62, 2) Then
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(1, -12)
        destRng = ptArr(i, 1)
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(0, 1)
    ElseIf ptArr(i, 1) = ptWS.Cells(74, 2) Then
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(1, -12)
        destRng = ptArr(i, 1)
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(0, 1)
    ElseIf ptArr(i, 1) = ptWS.Cells(86, 2) Then
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(1, -12)
        destRng = ptArr(i, 1)
        Set destRng = destRng.Offset(0, 1)
    Else: destRng = ptArr(i, 1)
    Set destRng = destRng.Offset(0, 1)
    End If

Next i
```

It gives me what I want for WS1.  However I have to repeat this for the 3 other worksheets.

For the other 3 worksheets, the total range is the same as posted above, just offset by 1 column.

```vb
      WS1 = ptWS.Range("B4:B97")
   
      WS2 = ptWS.Range("C4:C97")

      WS3 = ptWS.Range("D4:D97")

      WS4 = ptWS.Range("E4:E97")
```

The destination starting point on all 4 worksheets are the same `Range(E6")`.

How do I add a loop through the worksheets once all cells on WS1 have been set, while also offsetting the column by 1 from ptWS.  I'm wondering if this can be done without copy/pasting the existing array code 3 more times and just changing the ranges.

I achieved the same result by looping through the data on ptWS by using a series of Do Until loops but then eventually ran into the same issue.

Comment: That first line makes it *not* look like an 8x12 grid - is that correct?  If Yes maybe you can expand on that a bit...

Comment: Yes that's correct.  Forgot to touch on that... so really a 7x12 and 1x10

Comment: Do those first two "missing" values have content that might be overwritten if adding a full 8x12 array to the sheet, or will they always be blank on the sheet?

Comment: No actual values will be in C6&D6, ever.  Only items in these cells is a ActiveX CheckBox/TextBox

Comment: Why haven't you used `.Resize()` together with `.Offset()` to target a range of cells in a table, instead of one cell at a time?

Comment: Why is the first statement target column "E" and all other statements column "C". This discrepancy makes the looping difficult.

Comment: @JAlex - check the comments above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one appraoch:

```vba
Sub Tester()
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To 4
        ColToMatrix ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PT").Range("B4:B97").Offset(0, i - 1), _
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS" & i).Range("C6")
    Next i

End Sub

'pass in the column to be mapped and the top-left destination cell for the matrix
Sub ColToMatrix(rngCol As Range, rngTL As Range)
    Dim arr, mtx(1 To 8, 1 To 12), i As Long, r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    arr = rngCol.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        n = i + 2 'account for starting 3 cells in
        r = 1 + ((n - 1) \ 12)
        c = ((n - 1) Mod 12) + 1
        mtx(r, c) = arr(i, 1)
    Next i
    rngTL.Resize(8, 12).Value = mtx
End Sub
```

Comment: Got this to work, just modified  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS" & i).Range("C6")

But thanks to your comment below the For i = , it was just accounting for the 2 empty cells twice which was making the starting cell G6 instead of E6

Comment: Okay, Tim.  I tried understanding the n, r, and c math variables and I'm lost.  
When i = 1, n = 3, which would make r = 1.16?  Am I thinking wrong?  I'm not sure where/how this number is used in the grand scheme.  If it's not too much trouble, would you be able to explain?

Comment: Regular division is / (forward slash) but there's also integer division https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/backslash-operator in which "Any fractional portion is truncated" and that is done using a *backslash*.   It would be equivalent to `Application.Floor([calc here], 1)`

Comment: Okay, that fills in the gaps.  Using it as the mtx row #, I thought maybe it was being rounded somewhere, I just had no idea where. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

To do this, better way is doing a sub to transpose data, and then call it for every worksheet.

I'm excluding `roneWS.Range("E6:N6") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B4:B13"))` because it's not part of the 7x12 array, due to different size (it's 10 values, not 12).

So we focus on 7x12, this part of your code:

```
roneWS.Range("C7:N7") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B14:B25"))
roneWS.Range("C8:N8") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B26:B37"))
roneWS.Range("C9:N9") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B38:B49"))
roneWS.Range("C10:N10") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B50:B61"))
roneWS.Range("C11:N11") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B62:B73"))
roneWS.Range("C12:N12") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B74:B85"))
roneWS.Range("C13:N13") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B86:B97"))
```

This sub will as for:

1. A source range like `ptWS.Range("B14:B97")`, 84 values (7x12)
2. A destiny range like `roneWS.Range("C7:N13")`, a 7x12 grid

The code is:

```
Sub GET_VALUES(ByVal vRngSource As Range, ByVal vRngDestiny As Range)
Dim vMatriz As Variant
Dim ZZ As Long
Dim ThisColumn As Long, ThisRow As Long
ThisColumn = 1
ThisRow = 1

vMatriz = vRngSource.Value
For ZZ = 1 To UBound(vMatriz) Step 1
    vRngDestiny.Cells(ThisRow, ThisColumn).Value = vMatriz(ZZ, 1)
    If ThisColumn = 12 Then
        ThisColumn = 1
        ThisRow = ThisRow + 1
    Else
        ThisColumn = ThisColumn + 1
    End If
Next ZZ

Erase vMatriz

End Sub
```

To call it, you can just do:

```
Sub test()
GET_VALUES Range("B14:B97"), Range("C7:N13")
End Sub
```

[image]

Now you just need to call it once for every worksheet. I would use a `For each loop` combined with `Select Case`, so you can choose for every worksheet what to do, like this:

```
Sub TEST()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim WK As Worksheet
Dim ptWS As Worksheet
Set ptWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PT")


For Each WK In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case WK.Name
        Case "WS1"
            GET_VALUES ptWS.Range("B14:B97"), WK.Range("C7:N13")
            WK.Range("E6:N6") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("B4:B13"))
        Case "WS2"
            GET_VALUES ptWS.Range("C14:C97"), WK.Range("C7:N13")
            WK.Range("E6:N6") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("C4:C13"))
        Case "WS3"
            GET_VALUES ptWS.Range("D14:D97"), WK.Range("C7:N13")
            WK.Range("E6:N6") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("D4:D13"))
        Case "WS4"
            GET_VALUES ptWS.Range("E14:E97"), WK.Range("C7:N13")
            WK.Range("E6:N6") = Application.Transpose(ptWS.Range("E4:E13"))
        Case Else
            'we do nothing
    End Select
Next WK

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: I was able to get this to work, I appreciate the solution/explanation!